# Trying To install meanjs

Tags: node.js, meanjs

[Iam Trying To Run meanjs with gulp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrMN9.png)

But It shows Me That!

```
    $ gulp
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'vinyl'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bl4ckvghost/TOOLS & PROGRAMS/meanjs/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js:2:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

- mongodb latest version
- npm latest version
- bower latest version
- gulp latest version

> I Want To Know How To Run Meanjs

System: Debian Jessie

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your node modules and installing it again:

```
      rm -rf ./node_modules
      npm cache clean
      npm install
```